# Random numbers not random

Tags: java, random

I'm making a game in Java where I need dices. There are 3 dices for the attacker and 2 dices for the defencer. This is my code that randomize the eyes on all dices:

```
        if (attacker.getArmies() > 1)
            aDices[0] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (attacker.getArmies() > 2)
            aDices[1] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (attacker.getArmies() > 3)
            aDices[2] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (defencer.getArmies() > 0)
            dDices[0] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (defencer.getArmies() > 1)
            dDices[1] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
```

But why are the numbers of the 'defence' dices mostly higher then the 'attack' dices?

I'm using the Random class from java.util.Random

Comment: Can you substantiate your claim?

Comment: How many times do you mean my "mostly higher"?

Comment: do you seed your random number generator?

Comment: See http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: I'm making the game 'Risk'. Its also a board game. When you play the game with real dices then the defencer has a lower 'win rate' then the attacker.

Comment: @IonutHulub Seeding is irrelevant here.

Comment: I know which Dilbert that is without even looking ;-)

Comment: @Marko Topolnik it is not. if he doesn't the program might generate the same numbers every time it starts and this might explain why the values for defence are always higher.

Comment: Without showing or describing some example data or statistics, this question probably cannot be answered. The distribution you see may be well within expected random variation.

Comment: @IonutHulub Only if he uses a ridiculously small sample size---but now that I say it, maybe he does!

Comment: Maybe your attacker doesn't have enough armies?

Comment: To sum up, OP, the problem is not in the random number generator, but in your program logic.

Comment: Any chance on marking an answer, or are you looking for more ellaboration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that you are using exactly the same function for attack and defense, it's simply impossible that the outcome is structurally higher for attackers. What you could try to convince yourself is write a little function that rolls the dice a 100 times as attack and defense and calculate averages for that. And even then it is still possible that after a 100 times, attack wins a 100 times, unlikely, but possible. That's the nature of randomness.

This is a nice short read on randomness for some background information:

http://engineering.mit.edu/live/news/1753-can-a-computer-generate-a-truly-random-number

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the Random class in combination with timestamps from your PC clock.
It's called a seed for the randomizer.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the code you're showing is giving more of an advantage to the defender than original Risk does;

```
if (attacker.getArmies() > 1)          // 1 army will never roll the dice
    aDices[0] = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
```

- The attacker gets 1 dice roll per army (1-3) he attacks with. You're giving him 0-2. That would mean that an attack with one army will never succeed.
- The defender gets 1 dice roll per army (1-2) he defends with. You're giving him 1-2.

That would tilt the game more towards the defender than original risk does, *all without getting biased random numbers*.